# textbox size issue in safari 4

Tags: html, safari, textbox

If I give the textbox size as 2, textbox is displaying of size 2 in all browsers.

```
<input type="text" size="2" name="day" />
```

But in safari 4, the size is less than 2. It means only 1 character is showing in textbox.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Any extra padding, margin, min-width, width etc.?

Answer (score 0):

when page loads try to find out in which browser it is currently running(Using javascript). then based on the browser give the size property of text box using javascript